# Join two tables and send as one record

Tags: java, rest, javafx, fxml

Suppose, that we have such tables:

**Table Users**

```
iduser | password
```

**Table Marks**

```
id | iduser | mark | idtest
```

**Table Tests**

```
idtest | title
```

Query looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}/marks")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Object funkcja(@PathParam("id") Integer iduser) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("select m,t from Marks m, Tests t where m.idusers=:iduser and m.idtest = t.idtests");
    query.setParameter("iduser", id);
    List<Object> results = (List<Object>)query.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

I have entity classes:
**Marks** , **Users**, **Tests**

What I should to do in order to join tables and send JSON type on web service and how to convert JSON to entity class because I would like to show in TableView.
Perhaps there are other simple ways?
Maybe **map** or **JsonObject**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have multiple questions here; I think you need to break these down into separate questions.

For the "main" question, which is about JPA and how to join the entities, I would do that at the entity level, not at the query level. I.e. I think I would have entity classes like:

```
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Tests")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @Column(name="idtest")
    private int id ;
    private String title ;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Test) {
            return Objects.equals(title, ((Test)other).title);
        } else return false ;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(title);
    }
}
```

and then the `Mark` entity can use a `@ManyToOne` annotation to reference the actual `Test` object (not its id):

```
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Marks")
public class Mark {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id ;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idtest")
    private Test test ;

    // You probably don't want a reference to User here, as the User class
    // encapsulates the password, which you don't want to throw back and
    // forward across the network unnecessarily. But if the User class 
    // instead had a user name etc you wanted, you could use the same
    // @ManyToOne technique to reference a User object here if you needed.
    @Column(name="iduser")
    private int userId ;

    private int mark ;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public int getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(int mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Mark) {
            Mark other = (Mark)obj ;
            return Objects.equals(userId, other.userId)
                && Objects.equals(test, other.test)
                && mark == other.mark ;
        } else return false ;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userId, test, mark);
    }
}
```

Now your query looks like

```
TypedQuery<Mark> query = em.createQuery("select m from Mark m where m.userId=:userid");
query.setParameter("userid", iduser);
List<Mark> results = query.getResultList();
```

and the `Mark` instances in the list already have all the data you need:

```
for (Mark mark : results) {
    System.out.println(mark.getTest().getTitle() + ": " + mark.getMark());
}
```

For the remaining questions:

Assuming you have a server set up with a JAX-RS implementation (e.g. Jersey) the code snippet you showed (modified with the new query) should generate JSON output. (You can use a developer tool such as Firefox REST client to view the JSON output by specifying the appropriate URL and request headers, and viewing the response.)

On the client (JavaFX) side you can use Jersey's client library (or maybe Apache HttpComponent library) to create the web requests easily, and a library such as GSON or Jackson for mapping the JSON content you get back to a Java object for display in the `TableView`.

I recommend trying this and asking specific questions about the remaining pieces if you get stuck.

Comment: You can also look at a [blog post](http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2014/05/09/one-bean-to-bind-them-all/) I wrote a couple of years ago. The main point of that was showing how to make your entities work with JavaFX properties (so you can easily use the same classes on the server and client); but it also describes the end-end application. I used Spring MVC instead of JAX-RS/Jersey to implement the web service in that example.

Comment: Perfect. It works very nice but I have little problem which is show column **title**. Code is [here](http://pastebin.com/5iTYJPbj). How I can resolve the problem?

Comment: Ask a new question: post code that is causing you trouble.

Comment: I wrote a new question. Thanks James